# Знак ? в регулярном выражении

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Вопрос такой: Что означает первый знак ? слева в скобках

```
\.(?i:gif|jpe?g|png)$
```

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F#%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B

Comment: @mike А что означает двоеточие после ?i (на вики не нашел)

Comment: Прочитайте внимательно текст прямо под таблицей на вики (цитата: _Если использование модификаторов требуется только в пределах группы, то нужный шаблон указывается внутри группы после модификаторов но перед двоеточием_)

Comment: Хотя это предложение конечно как то странно читается... Но пример в следующем предложении все объясняет

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Всё, что Вы прочтете ниже- плод моих фантазий, этого нет в учебниках и книгах. Это- моя попытка простыми словами объяснить смысл `(?` в регулярных выражениях.

Представьте, что Вы пишите язык регулярных выражений с нуля, так проще всего будет понять, что обозначает `(?` в регулярных выражениях.

Для начала:
Некое выражение, заключенное в скобки называется в регулярных выражениях группой

```
(это группа)
```

Итак, мы создаем язык регулярных выражений с нуля и мы не хотим перегружать язык множеством мета-символов и при этом нам ещё надо описать языком кучу возможностей:

- атомарную группировку
- именованные группы
- группы без сохранения
- рекурсии
- изменение флагов внутри регулярного выражения
- и много-много других

А что бы мы сделали, если бы писали новый императивный язык? Мы бы написали кучу стандартных функций:

- function atomic( expression ) { [native code] }
- function isNamedGroup( expression ) { [native code] }
- function groupWithoutCapture( expression ) { [native code] }
- и так далее

## Грубо говоря

`(?` обозначает, что к группе необходимо применить некую **функцию** языка регулярных выражений.

А с таким пониманием всё становится очень просто:

- `(?> ... )` - атомарная группировка
- `(?P<name> ... )` - именованная группа
- `(?: ... )` - группа без сохранения захваченного
- `(?R)` - рекурсия
- `(?i ... )` - изменение флага внутри группы
- и много-много других, полный список в учебниках и гайдах

Всё это объединяет одно- конструкция начинается с `(?`, применяется до закрывающей `)` и каким-либо образом добавляет функционал для обработки текста.

Answer (score 1):

```
(?i:
```

значит "case **i**nsensitive" - что поиск (до соответствующей закрывающей скобки) *не будет делать разницу между прописными и строчными буквами*.

И так ваше выражение

```
\.(?i:gif|jpe?g|png)$
```

будет например успешно так для `.gif` как и для `.GIF`, `.gIf`, `.jpg` `.JPG` `.pNg` итд.